# SharePoint 2016 supports SQL SERVER 2017

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sql-server-2017

We have to deploy SharePoint 2016 production farm for Intranet portal can we use now SQL Server 2017 as back-end and high availability with Always on

Comment: Check also the list of all **[Supported and Unsupported SQL Server for SharePoint 2019 and 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-best-practices-sharepoint/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use SQL server 2017 with high availability always on.

Reference - [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d88c402-24f2-449b-86a6-6e7afcfec0cd(v=office.16)#section4)

[Overview of SQL Server in a SharePoint Server 2016 environment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff945791(v=office.16).aspx#HA)

Comment: in my current environment sharpoint 2013 i am using reporting services sharepoint mode how can i migrate to new sql server 2017?

Comment: That might be a long answer and it can't be given in comments section :) , can you accept this as answer and ask a separate question related to migration ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it support SQL server 2017

Check

[SharePoint 2016 with SQL server](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/02/27/sql-server-2016-sp1-support-sharepoint-2016/)

[Overview of SQL Server in a SharePoint Server 2016 environment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff945791(v=office.16).aspx#HA)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use it, as it is supported version with SharePoint 2016. But if you are using the BI functionality then SQL Server 2017 no longer includes SQL Server Reporting Services integration with SharePoint.

[Supported combinations of SharePoint and Reporting Services server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/supported-combinations-of-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-server)

This means that you must stick with SQL Server 2016 for SSRS integration with SharePoint Server 2016 or move to SSRS Native, however like past versions of SSRS, you can host downlevel SSRS database on an uplevel version of SQL Server (e.g., SSRS 2016 databases on SQL Server 2017).

[SharePoint Server 2016 Supports SQL Server 2017](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2017/10/sharepoint-server-2016-supports-sql-server-2017/)

also check this one [Embed paginated reports into SharePoint using the Report Viewer web part](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/09/22/embed-paginated-reports-into-sharepoint-using-the-report-viewer-web-part/)